# Why does a PHP file not get included in the file when run by the server?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have one file called `showRelayTeams.php` and another called `databaseSELECTOperation.php`

I am trying to put the one with the database function into the one called `showRelayTeams.php`

showRelayTeam.php

```
<?php
$House = $_GET['q'];

$Data = "No Data";

$Query = "SELECT Firstname, Lastname, AgeGroup, Event, Value FROM tblEventEntries WHERE House = '" . $House . "' ORDER BY Value ASC;";

require("http://127.0.0.1/phpscripts/databaseOperations.php");

$Data = databaseSELECTOperation($Query);

$Counter = 0;

if (mysqli_num_rows($Data) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Age Group</th>";
    echo "<th>Event</th>";
    echo "<th>Time</th>";
    echo "<th>Select?</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Data)) {
        $Counter++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $Row["Firstname"] . " " . $Row["Lastname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $Row["AgeGroup"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $Row["Event"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $Row["Value"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" . $Counter . "'  
onclick='boxChecked(this.id)'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

databaseSELECTOperation.php

```
<?php
//use the SQL SELECT command and return the data
function databaseSELECTOperation($Query) {
    //this file will include the host, username, password and the database name
    include "http://127.0.0.1/includes/variables.php";

    //start a connection to the database using the credentials
    $Connection = mysqli_connect($DatabaseHost, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);

    //if the connection to the database was not successfully made then
    if (!$Connection) {
        //end the script and then print an error
        die("Could not connect to the database: " . mysqli_error());
    } //end if

    //run the query and put the data returned in to a variable
    $DataReturned = mysqli_query($Connection, $Query);

    //return the data to the script that called it
    return $DataReturned;
}
?>
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function databaseSELECTOperation()

When I insert the following code just after the require statement, I get

> function not found

```
<?php
if (function_exists('databaseSELECTOperation')) {
    echo "function found.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "function not found<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You're requiring it via http, so it will get the parsed response from that page, not the code. Try using the absolute file path instead.

Comment: You're including a HTTP page at *require()*. Change it to **require("databaseOperations.php");**.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Comment: The file is `databaseOperations.php` or `databaseSELECTOperation.php`?

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo Thank you thats solved it

Comment: @aynber Thank you thats solved it

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton since its a select box, wouldn't that mean the user cant put in anything so its safe, but ill have a read for the other text boxes on the website, thanks

Comment: @SammySimpson That is an incorrect assumption, I can go to any website that I want to and right click any select element and click "Inspect Element", and I can change any value to anything that I want.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you make a good point, thanks for the help

Comment: @SammySimpson No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the error:

```
require("http://127.0.0.1/phpscripts/databaseOperations.php");
```

When you are referring to the file via URL, it is including the output which is already processed by a web server, while you need to include the source PHP code.

Instead, you need to specify the path to the file on the file system like in the following examples:

```
require('../phpscripts/databaseOperations.php');
require('/var/www/html/phpscripts/databaseOperations.php');
require('C:\inetpub\html\phpscripts\databaseOperations.php');
```